# How to copy multiple records from a datagridview into another form using VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've a project that I am working on which I intend to copy from the rows selected just the oldcomputername column value and pass to a task form. On the Task from I've created a textbox (Number of systems)to display the number of oldcomputername copied from the datagridview in table (inventory). from my code, I can only copy a single record and I'd like to copy based on how many records are selected. Can anyone help me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is my copy for the Assign Task button:

```
Try
    Me.Hide()
    Dim MyAssignments As New MyAssignments
    MyAssignments.ShowDialog()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

[image]

For the Task form load event I have this code:

```
Dim a As Integer

a = frmInventoryTest.InventoryDGV.CurrentRow.Index
Me.TaskNameTextBox.Text = frmInventoryTest.InventoryDGV.Item(1, a).Value.ToString
```

Comment: If you want to copy from the rows selected then you should be using the `SelectedRows` property.  It's a collection so you can loop over it.  Get the values from the rows in the loop and put them is a `List` or the like and then populate your `TextBox` from that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thanks for your reply. Is it possible to send a sample code on can achieve this task. Thanks again.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can please send a code based on what i've provided on how to use the selectedRows property? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am trying the following code:                                                  Try

            For Each rows In source.SelectedRows
                Dim cell As DataGridViewCellCollection = rows.cells
                Dim row As String() = New String()
                INVDGV2.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment, the code could look something like this:

```
Dim lines As New List(Of String)

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In myDataGridView.SelectedRows
    lines.Add(row.Cells(1).Value.ToString())
Next

myTextBox.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

Comment: thanks for your help again. The code is working but not the way I want it. I am getting all the records in myTextBox line but I'd like to have each single record in a separate myTextbox, so that when I assign the batch to a specific technician he would be able to see all the system that he needs to reimage. Thanks again I really appreciated your help.

Comment: thanks for your help again. The code is working but not the way I want it. I am getting all the records in myTextBox line but I'd like to have each single record in a separate myTextbox, so that when I assign the batch to a specific technician he would be able to see all the system that he needs to reimage. Thanks again I really appreciated your help.

Comment: If you really want to do that, which sounds like a bad idea to me, then you're going to have to actually create the TextBoxes at the time because you won't know how many there need to be until then.  Why wouldn't you just use a ListBox?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Perhaps, I am not make myself clear on what I am trying to do. The idea to copy selected record or records from a datagridview then assign all the selected records as an to a specific technician. From here, when the technician access his assignments, all of the these computers should show-up as a single rows. Example: 1 row: 1Computer Technician, 2 row: 2computer Technician, 3 row: 3 computer technician, something like this. Thank you again for your time and dedication. Many thanks.

Comment: what would be the way to get this done considering my idea? Thanks again.